Run github action only if all checks for current commit have passed
I want to run a github action on schedule, or triggered by workflow_dispatch.
However, the action should only run if another action ran successfully at some point, for the most recent commit: if the current commit has a "✔".
Example:

I have a "run unit tests" action running on each push
I have a "run unit tests after updating all dependencies", running once per week, but only if the regular unit tests pass.

How can I configure a trigger for this github action?

I suggest creating a reusable workflow for the run unit tests. Then, you could call this reusable in 2 other workflows: The first one that would trigger on each push, the second one that would trigger on schedule. In the second workflow, there would be 2 jobs: the first one would use the reusable workflow, and the second job would be the "run unit tests after updating all dependencies" process,  with the second job requiring the first job to be completed using the need keyword.
